# call R ggplot with Rexcel

Tags: r, vba, ggplot2, rexcel

I click on a excel macro button which uses RExcel to execute an R script that generates a matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]    0    0   -3   -3   -3   -3   -2
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    4    4    4
 [3,]    0    0    0    1    2    1    2
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
[12,]    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
[13,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[14,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[15,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[16,]    0   -1    3    3    3    4    3
[17,]    0    1    2    2    2    1    0
[18,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[19,]    0   -1   -2   -2   -2   -1   -1
[20,]    0   -2   -2   -3   -3   -5   -4
[21,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[22,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[23,]    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
[24,]    0    0    1    1    1    0    1
[25,]    0    0    1    1    1    0    1
[26,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    2
[27,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
[28,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[29,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[30,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[31,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

and I change this to a data.frame. set a browser() right before

```
ggplot(melt(graphPrep),aes(value,fill=variable)) + geom_histogram(position = "dodge",binwidth = 1/(buckWidth-1)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = min(graphPrep):max(graphPrep))
```

you can use 5 for buckWidth, and breaks -5:5 if you're replicating

then put that line into R, hit enter, and it makes a nice plot.
However, if I just press "n" a couple times to try to execute that line (or remove the browser entirely), the graph never shows up.

I'd like to make this completely executable from excel, but as-is I'm defining

```
drawIt <- function()
  {
    ggplot(melt(graphPrep),aes(value,fill=variable)) + geom_histogram(position = "dodge",binwidth = 1/(buckWidth-1)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = min(graphPrep):max(graphPrep))
  }
```

and making the user "drawIt()" in the r console. I'd like to just have this work in excel...

Answer (score 1):

as embarrassing as this is, I'm going to leave it up in case others have this same problem

```
print(drawIt())
```